# How can I pass user credentials through a Unix-domain socket on Mac OS X?

Tags: security, macos, sockets

Under many operating systems Unix-domain sockets allow a process to reliably pass its credentials to another process in a way that can't be maliciously subverted.  For instance, this is done on Linux through the [SO_PASSCRED and SO_PEERCRED options](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket), on FreeBSD [by passing messages that include the cmsgcred structure](http://books.google.gr/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA429&lpg=PA429&source=web&ots=Kq2FUpbqTu&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result), and on NetBSD [by setting the LOCAL_CREDS option](http://julipedia.blogspot.com/2006/08/more-on-localcreds.html).  However, I haven't been able to find a way to perform this operation under Mac OS X.  The corresponding header (socket.h) seems to have the functionality disabled for Apple's build.

```
#if !defined(_POSIX_C_SOURCE) || defined(_DARWIN_C_SOURCE)
#ifndef __APPLE__
// ...
struct cmsgcred {
```

Any idea of another Mac OS X facility that can accomplish the same result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't ever worked with it, but I think you're looking for LOCAL_PEERCRED. ( see man unix)

*You can confirm the identity of the program at the other end of the socket using the LOCAL_PEERCRED socket option, introduced in Mac OS X 10.4.*

See [Technical Note TN2083. Daemons and Agents](http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2005/tn2083.html)

Comment: Indeed, following your pointer, I found the option documented in unix(4).  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Even better, thanks to the accepted answer, I found that getpeereid(), directly returns the required data.